# Cannot locate elements by XPath on Python

Tags: python, selenium, xpath, python-requests, webdriverwait

I was trying to get the websites of firms from Bloomberg using XPath. I was stuck because it always return an empty list. I did several tests and found I can't locate any elements on this webpage. This is the code I'm using.

```
import re 
import requests
from lxml import html

url = "https://www.bloomberg.com/profile/company/FWLT:US"
requests=requests.get(url)
tree = html.fromstring(requests.content)
website = tree.xpath('//*[@id="root"]/div/section/div[2]/section/div/section[7]/div/text()')
print(website)
```

I also tried selenium but ended up in the same problem. Can someone help me solve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using [Selenium](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54459701/what-is-selenium-and-what-is-webdriver/54482491#54482491) to print the text **[www.amecfw.com](http://www.amecfw.com)** you can use either of the following [Locator Strategies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48369043/official-locator-strategies-for-the-webdriver/48376890#48376890):

- Using *xpath*, *following* and `get_attribute()`:

  ```
  print(driver.find_element_by_xpath("//h2[text()='WEBSITE']//following::div").get_attribute("innerHTML"))
  ```
- Using *xpath*, *following-sibling* and *text* attribute:

  ```
  print(driver.find_element_by_xpath("//h2[text()='WEBSITE']//following-sibling::div").text)
  ```

---

Ideally, to print the text **[www.amecfw.com](http://www.amecfw.com)** you have to induce [WebDriverWait](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49775502/webdriverwait-not-working-as-expected/49775808#49775808) for the `visibility_of_element_located()` and you can use either of the following [Locator Strategies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48369043/official-locator-strategies-for-the-webdriver/48376890#48376890):

- Using *xpath*, *following* and `get_attribute()`:

  ```
  print(WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//h2[text()='WEBSITE']//following::div"))).get_attribute("innerHTML"))
  ```
- Using *xpath*, *following-sibling* and *text* attribute:

  ```
  print(WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//h2[text()='WEBSITE']//following-sibling::div"))).text)
  ```
- **Note** : You have to add the following imports :

  ```
  from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
  from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
  from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
  ```

> You can find a relevant discussion in [How to retrieve the text of a WebElement using Selenium - Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55240245/how-to-retrieve-the-text-of-a-webelement-using-selenium-python/55241232#55241232)

---

### Outro

Link to useful documentation:

- [`get_attribute()`](https://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/py/webdriver_remote/selenium.webdriver.remote.webelement.html#selenium.webdriver.remote.webelement.WebElement.get_attribute) method `Gets the given attribute or property of the element.`
- [`text`](https://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/py/webdriver_remote/selenium.webdriver.remote.webelement.html#selenium.webdriver.remote.webelement.WebElement.text) attribute returns `The text of the element.`
- [Difference between text and innerHTML using Selenium](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40416048/difference-between-text-and-innerhtml-using-selenium/55902072#55902072)

Answer (score 0):

this will get you the website value -

```
website = tree.xpath('//h2[contains(text(), \'WEBSITE\')]/following-sibling::div')
```

be aware that I've escaped the single quotes from 'WEBSITE'

Comment: Hi Alin, I tried yours but it still doesn't work. In fact, it returns empty list no matter what XPath I'm using...

Comment: that's because the website block unusual access - try to print "tree" - you will find this "We\'ve detected unusual activity from your computer network</h2>\n        <p class="continue">To continue, please click the box below to let us know you\'re not a robot